# How to get rid of show-through crop marks from header?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've tried uncheck  Show crop mark in Options already. Just like repaint the paragraph with a new shade.

Bleeding through crop marks:

[image]

Comment: This might help : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/839371/margin-marks-or-crop-marks-appear-on-each-corner-of-the-page-when-you

Comment: Well, I figured out it's not the crop mark it's just a vertical white line.

Comment: Then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I **Maggied** the whole doc into a fresh one with uncorrupted normal.dotm. And that did the trick. –